# History of master password for Keepass database

Tags: windows, keepass

1. Where can I check when I changed master password for database last time or previously?
2. Is there possibility to set reminder that I have not changed the master password for let's say 2 months?

Comment: Did you do any previous research? Did you have a look at the options the tool provides?

Comment: I did have a look to options even Advanced but I somehow missed the mentioned last part of it. I am sorry about that. I searched via duckduckgo on keepass.info and read all superuser questions related to keepass master password. Is this somewhere mentioned (i.e. documentation)?

Comment: Don't sweat it. As it was easy enough to find I was just wondering. Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) including information about what you've tried so far is a really good thing to include in your question. So others can see that you did try to solve it yourself. Looks like there is a comment on the [sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/1a6df001/?limit=25) but it's not included in the documentation itself. Have a good time on superuser and in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: KeePass - Advanced Database Settings]

For your second part just check File, Database Settings and Advanced.